# Vuejs set value of hidden input as route param

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am trying to set the value of a hidden input with a value of id so that when I submit my form, I have the id. I know that this value is being passed using a param as follows:

```
  <td><router-link :to="{ name: 'editclient', params: { id: client.id }}">Edit</router-link></td>
```

Then in my EditClient component I have the following hidden input:

```
 <input type="hidden" value="{{this.$route.params.id}}" v-model="id">
```

The issue is that this won't compile, is there another way to do this?

I can see that the value of my id is set to 1 which is what it should be in this case:
[image]

However the issue is that I can't bind this to my hidden input.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case I would probably just use `v-model`

```
<input type="hidden" v-model="id">
```

And then set `id` either in data or when the route changes.

```
data(){
    return {
        id: this.$route.params.id
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: odd, it still seems to say that value is null yet I can see it in $route.params.id : <input type="hidden" value="">

Comment: Well, what is 'id'.

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference incase someone else hits this issue, I managed to solve this by using a computed attribute in my component:

```
  computed: {
            id () {
                return this.$route.params.id
            }
        },
```